# How to overcome maven org.eclipse.persistence JAR signature error

Tags: security, maven, persistence, eclipselink

Im trying to add the `modelgen` jar to my maven project to enable automatic Metamodel class generation however I am getting the following error when I try to compile the project:

```
Failed to execute goal org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:2.2.4:process (process) on project Project-per: Error executing: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProperties"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

As best as I can determine there is most likely a miss match in the JAR signatures causing this. However I don't understand why or how to fix the problem.

My POM (Relevant parts only)

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-RC2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.nosql</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-RC2</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

NB. Everything works fine with the nosql and the eclipselink, its just when I add the modelgen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, as best I can tell I was right, the problem was caused by a signature difference in the JAR files. How this can happen on a library as popular as eclipselink is beyond me but hey.

My solution was to use a snapshot as they are generally not signed. Given that I was unable to obtain snapshot from central I used the following repo to obtain it;

```xml
<repository>
    <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following dependency into pom

```
<pluginExecution>
                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                      <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                      <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                      <versionRange>[2.2.4,)</versionRange>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <action>
                      <ignore />
                    </action>
</pluginExecution>
```